How to use webmin for apcupsd
I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/apcupsd to install apcupsd which worked and it is running. I followed the instructions at the bottom to install Webmin and apcupsd-cgi. These appear to have worked, but I can't work out how to use Webmin to control the UPS. Can anyone point me in the right direction. To clarify, I can view Webmin at https://localhost:10000/, but I can't see any interface to apcupsd.
Edit: This page https://sites.google.com/view/ubuntuserver16-04/install-your-distro-to-build-your-base-server/put-the-apc-monitoring-module-in-webmin says to

Go to "Webmin->Webmin Configuration" from the left hand menu and click on "Webmin Modules". Click "Third party module from" and enter http://diego.caravana.to/wp-content/apcupsd0.812.wbm.gz into the address box to the right and then click on the install module button.

However when I try that I get download timeout.
Further edit: I have realised that there is a search feature for the third party modules, but apcupsd is not in there.
Further edit: I found a video on Youtube where there was a screen shot of the site given in my first link. At that time it had instructions about installing the third party module. These have been removed from the section about using webmin, which made me wonder if it is now built in - but I can't find it. However one of the reasons I wanted to use webmin for apcupsd was to check the battery level. I have now noticed that this is given instead of the normal shutdown symbol for the quick settings menu:

And if you click on it, the quick settings menu gives the %age of battery left. So if I can't get webmin to work it's not so important.

I've been researching similar for apcupsd and so far have come up with this manpage and also this resource. Neither refer to webmin specifically but to using apcupsd in terminal.

Please be aware that this instruction is from 2017, and so is this video that shows the process. It is highly likely that this is no longer working completely as expected.

Also, the relevant Webmin module can be downloaded here. Again, please beware that the date of this module is from 2006 (~ancient). So possibly it needs some modifications.

what does this have to do with universal power supplies?!

did you try installing and configuring NUT (Network UPS Tools) from the software store?

I'll say this again: The instructions and the module is at least 7 years old, which mean it's most likely abandoned. I'm sorry, but this seems like a lost cause.

@graham. I've not tried NUT. Since I now have my battery percentage showing in the status bar, and apcupsd will shut down the PC on low battery level, I'll leave things as they are. But if I re instal Ubuntu, I will try NUT. Many thanks.
